# Replace all values in a row after a selection

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute a MySQL command in phpMyAdmin so that I can replace all the value in a column AFTER selecting certain values from another column specific values.

The query I am using to select them is this:

```
SELECT * FROM `homes` WHERE `world` LIKE '%plot%'
```

However, I am trying to replace all the values in column after selecting them all:

```
SELECT world,server, REPLACE(server,'drug','plots') FROM homes WHERE world='%plot%'
```

I am not entirely sure that's what i need to do but here is an image explaining it a bit more.

[image]

I have also tried these queries but without any luck:

```
update homes set server = "plots" where world = '%plot%';
SELECT world,server, REPLACE(server,'drug','plots') FROM homes WHERE world='%plot%'
```

Comment: Don't you want `like` in the second query too?

Comment: @shawnt00 Basically I am trying to change everything that says "drug" with "plots". In that screenshot, i have selected them all, but I am stuck where to go next as I have tried many things but they all didn't work.

Comment: It's been a while since I last used phpMyAdmin but can't you just do it with an UPDATE query..?

Comment: You'll have to describe what it did that's wrong. The `replace` looks correct if I understand your desired output. So I think your 2nd `where` clause may be the problem.

Comment: @shawnt00 Yes well my second query i tried came up saying that it came back with an empty result. Meaning it was a valid command but it did nothing.

Comment: @obe I have tried this, using this command UPDATE homes SET server=plots WHERE world LIKE '%plot%'; However this still doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: You would probably get an empty result if you used `=` instead of `like`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but do you mean something like this?

```
SELECT  world
,       server
,       case server 
          when 'drug' then 'differentValue'
          when 'med' then 'anotherdifferentValue'
        end server2  
FROM homes 
WHERE world like 'plot%'
```